# How to make a function to categorizing variable values with percentile(quantile) in R?

Tags: r

"data" is a data.frame and has 10 numeric variables. I want to make all the variables as categorized variables with 6 percentile groups (under 5%, between 5%~25%, between 25%~50%, between 50%~75%, between 75%~95%, over 95%)
I want to make it with a function so I can categorize all the variables all at ones.

I can only do this without a function as below, so I have to repeat the same codes over and over.

```
m1<- quantile(data$val, 0.05)
m2<- quantile(data$val, 0.25)
m3<- quantile(data$val, 0.5)
m4<- quantile(data$val, 0.75)
m5<- quantile(data$val, 0.95)

data$val[data$val<m1]  = "below0.05"
data$val[data$val>= m1& data$val<m2 ]  = "0.05to0.25"
data$val[data$val>= m2& data$val<m3 ]  = "0.25to0.5"
data$val[data$val>= m3& data$val<m4 ]  = "0.5to0.75"
data$val[data$valT>= m4& data$val<m5 ]  = "0.75to0.95"
data$val[data$val>= m5]  = "upper0.95"

data$val <-as.factor(data$val)
```

I tried some codes with lapply() and function(data,name)

```
fun =function(data, name) {
  y <-get(name,data)
   m1<- quantile(name,data, 0.05)
   m2<- quantile(name,data, 0.25)
   m3<- quantile(name,data, 0.5)
   m4<- quantile(name,data, 0.75)
   m5<- quantile(name,data, 0.95)
   RB = rbind(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5)
   dimnames(RB)[[2]] = "Value"

   name$data[ name$data<m1]  = "below0.05"
   name$data[ name$data>= m1& name$data<m2 ]  = "0.05to0.25"
   name$data[ name$data>= m2& name$data<m3 ]  = "0.25to0.5"
   name$data[ name$data>= m3& name$data<m4 ]  = "0.5to0.75"
   name$data[ name$data>= m4& name$data<m5 ]  = "0.75to0.95"
   name$data[ name$data>= m5]  = "upper0.95"

   name$data <-as.factor(name$data)
}
```

It works only throughout the halfway. I want to know how to make it right.  Plus, I want to know how to apply "lapply()" here so that I can categorize all the variables easily. Please, anyone help!

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "name", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 301
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'name'. 
 Show Traceback
```

Rerun with Debug

Answer (score 3):

We can use `cut` to divide data into `breaks` using `quantile` and use `lapply` to apply it for multiple columns. So something like this should work for 1st 10 columns.

```
lapply(df[1:10], function(x) cut(x, 
    breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(x, c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95))), 
    labels = c("below0.05", "0.05to0.25", "0.25to0.5", "0.5to0.75", "0.75to0.95")))
```